# Aerospike: How to perform IN query on PK

Tags: lua, udf, aerospike

How to perform (sql like) IN queries in aerospike. 
Do we need an UDF for this?

Something like this: `Select * from ns.set where PK in (1,2,3)`

If this requires a UDF how to go about it as the UDF is executed on a key:

```
EXECUTE <module>.<function>(<args>) ON <ns>[.<set>] WHERE PK = <key>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically looking at retrieving records by a list of keys. This is a batch-read operation in Aerospike. Every language client for Aerospike should have this capability.

For example, in the Python client this is the [Client.get_many](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/client.html#aerospike.Client.get_many) method:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import aerospike
from aerospike.exception import AerospikeError
import sys

config = { 'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 3000)] }
client = aerospike.client(config).connect()

try:
    # assume the fourth key has no matching record
    keys = [
      ('test', 'demo', '1'),
      ('test', 'demo', '2'),
      ('test', 'demo', '3'),
      ('test', 'demo', '4')
    ]
    records = client.get_many(keys)
    print records
except AerospikeError as e:
    print("Error: {0} [{1}]".format(e.msg, e.code))
    sys.exit(1)
finally:
    client.close()
```

Similarly, in the Java client the [AerospikeClient.get()](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeClient.html#get(com.aerospike.client.policy.BatchPolicy,%20com.aerospike.client.Key[],%20java.lang.String...)) method can take a list of keys.

Comment: I totally misunderstood the question! However, as a separate problem, lets say one has composite keys such as abc:123, abc:456, abc:234...xyz:123, xyz:456 .. etc and I wanted all records that are abc:* key, you can now use predicate filtering with ver 3.12.1+ if you stored the key in a bin. Right?

Comment: Predicate filtering would be a great way to introspect bin information and quickly finding the matching records.

Answer (score 2):

In Ver 3.12.1+, you can run such queries if you store your Primary Key in a bin and then run predicate filtering on that bin. See http://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/predicate.html

Aerospike by default does not store the PK in its raw string or numeric form as you assign it. It stores a RIPEMD160 hash of the PK+Set name.